# Select-Box and not drop down list in Asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

Is there an alternative to the drop down list like a Select-Box in MVC2?  I have been looking around for a bit and the web seems a little ambiguous on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`Html.ListBoxFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor.aspx) which will generate a multiple select list box. The only difference with the `DropDownListFor` is that it addes the `multiple="multiple"` to the `<select>` tag that it generates and obviously the first parameter in the lambda expression must be a list property as you could have multiple selected values.